# How can I prevent this VBA script written to remove blanks in a column from stalling at the end?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following script written to remove blank cells in long column in excel

```
  Sub RemoveBlanks()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long

i = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While i <= 30000
Set Rng = Range("A" & i)


If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng) = 0 Then
Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng) = 1 Then
i = i + 1
Else: Stop

End If
Loop
End
End Sub
```

I want this to be a 'one size fits all' macro, so if there are only 20000 rows, the script will still run out until the end. I've been experimenting with adding another range `chunk` which is set as `rng, rng.offset(10,0)` and telling the script to increase i if this is empty too (as this is only empty at the end of the column) but this approach doesn't seem to be working. Is there another angle I can take on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a dynamic range:

replace

```
Do While i <= 30000
```

with

```
range = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Do While i <= range
```

Next thing is you have to update your range if you delete something, so after this line:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng) = 0 Then
    Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Add this code:

```
Range = Range -1
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I'm getting an `argument not valid` error for the first new line. Do I need to add `Dim Range As Range` earlier on? Doing that alone gives be an object error for the same line instead.

Comment: I fixed it by Dim'ing it as `Long` instead, and changing the name from range to something else. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your method should be starting at the bottom and working up. Failing to do this may results in skipped blanks when row **i** is deleted, the rows shift up but you increment **i** and carry on down.

However, your best bet is to use the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with the [xlCellTypeBlanks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) parameter.

```
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    with .columns(1)
        on error resume next
        .specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks).delete shift:=xlup
        on error goto 0
    end with
end with
```

This can be slow if a large number of discontiguous cells are being deleted. Probably not as slow as cycling through them all one at a time but still time consuming.

Comment: Great suggestion. Thanks. My particular script doesn't skip cells, because when row **i** is deleted, **i** doesn't increase.

Comment: Yes, that's true but you are also processing up to 60,000 [COUNTA function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/counta-function-47239e46-e523-40f4-94d7-fa2e1711fd4a) calculations. If you ran from the bottom to teh top at least the maximum would be 30,000.

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thanks.